# Adding pinch zoom in jblough's Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

Tags: android, pdf, pinchzoom, pdf-reader, pdfviewer

I am building an Android application where I am using this library to view PDF's.
https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

This allows me to view PDF, zoom and navigate to other PDF pages. Works fine. 
(However it takes a bit long time to load a few kb PDF when I tested in my Android Phone LG Optimus l5, ***any help with that?*** )

**Another problem** : It does not allow me to pinch zoom, it has two buttons for 'zoom in and zoom out' . that is very uneasy to work with. I want it to zoom with finger gesture .
Please look into the library and tell me if its possible to add 'pinch zoom' functionality.

ALSO, I looked at the libraries provided in this site : http://www.androidpdf.mobi/

Download the library from http://www.androidpdf.mobi/download/download-android to test

This is perfect for what I had in mind. Has pinch zoom functionality, slides to next pages, searches for text , etc and it was free. But later I read that its not absolutely free. I would need a licensed version to use it for a commercial app.

It will be helpful if anyone could suggest a basic library that can do the following :

- a) view PDF,
- b) pinch zoom functionality
- c) select text ( not necessary )
- d) **is absolutely free for use in commercial apps (like distribution or selling of apps)**

Either a modification of the jblough library will help or a suggestion for a new library. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this library https://github.com/bhavyahmehta/Pdf-Reader---Writer

The reader part of the library is under the GNU GPL licence which means you can use it for commercial purposes. It also means that if you modify or enhance the library at all you have to allow anyone to use and view the source code of that module (not your entire app). But it sounds like you only require it to view the pdf and use the functions that it already has, which is fine. I am no expert in licensing though so maybe just double check reading through the licensing agreement..